# install multple php version on centos 8

Tags: php, centos8

I have a server running on centos 8 PHP 7 is installed already and I'm new to centos 8.

I used to use centos 7 and I use the 2 PHP versions 7 and 5
I am using the php5 for some older scripts until I upgrade them
when I moved to centos 8.

I found that it doesn't support The Software Collections ( SCL ) Repository, where I found tutorials about how to use, it to install multiple PHP versions on centos, unfortunately, it's not supported in centos 8.

How can I install php5.6 on centos 8 besides php7?

Comment: Use containers, or just fix the scripts.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-centos-8 will solve this issue - i belive

Answer (score 0):

Try this process. I was able to install PHP 5.6 on Alma 8.9.

Open: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Select these choices:

```
OS: CentOS / Alma -> EL 8

Wanted PHP version: 5.6.40

Type of installation: multiple
```

---

It should show steps like this below the form:

Command to install:

```
# dnf  install php56
```

Command to install additional packages:

```
# dnf  install php56-php-xxx
```

Command to install testing packages:

```
# dnf --enablerepo=remi-test install php56-php-xxx
```

Command to check the installed version and available extensions:

```
# php56 --version
# php56 --modules
```

When a single version is installed, command in default path (/usr/bin/php) can be installed:

```
# dnf install php56-syspaths
```

---

See Remi's link below for a more complete process and to configure Apache's to SetHandler for various PHP versions.

Comment: Also read https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2022/02/17/My-PHP-Workstation